# Turning GSheets formula to raw text if cell is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Hi fellow google sheet enjoyers! I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for a long time. I hope someone can help me write the required script.

I made a test table, identical in structure to the real one:

[Sample table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vQdYSofLmuN4ZNvLhPduDGei2uzkRrVdq-3l87N-OOw/edit#gid=0)

It works like this:
-The client confirms his application by clicking on the pre-filled form
-After this, a line with the client number and a green dotappears on the “Confirmation - GForms” sheet.
-In the table on the “Main Table” sheet, this green dot appears using “VLOOKUP”. To prevent the table from being overloaded, I need the formula with "VLOOKUP" to turn into raw text when a green dot appears (when the result "VLOOOKUP" is not empty)

I'm sure there's an easier way to do all this, but I'm a noob at this.

I tried to put together a script in Apps Script from pieces of other people's posts from the forum, but nothing worked

Comment: We are not a code writing service.  If you have specific questions about  the code feel free to ask them, otherwise plan to develop most of the code on your own.

Comment: @Cooper I apologize if this post sounds like a requirement to write the code for me. I am asking for advice in which direction to look for information. I translate the text into English with the help of a translator, so the meaning and tone of the sentences may be unusual. I will be glad for any help

Comment: I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. About `I need the formula with "VLOOKUP" to turn into raw text when a green dot appears`, in your expected result, you want to convert the formulas to the raw text when the green dot is shown in the cell and replace the green dot with the formula converted to the raw text. In this case, the formula can be seen as the cell value instead of the formula. And you want to keep the formulas in the cells where the green dot is not shown. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike In general, correct, but I need to completely replace the contents of a cell with the VLOOKUP formula when the result of that VLOOKUP formula became ""

Comment: I made an automation script on Make.com, but it wastes too many operations. I found a script, but it only changes the first column. Maybe someone has a similar script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `but I need to completely replace the contents of a cell with the VLOOKUP formula when the result of that VLOOKUP formula became ""`, in this case, when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, you want to convert the cell value from `` to `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2;'Confirmation - from GForms'!A1:B;2))` of cell "P2" of "Main table" sheet. Is my understanding correct? In your situation, only column "P" is used?

Comment: @Tanaike 
From =IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2;'Confirmation - from GForms'!A1:B;2))
To 

When =IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2;'Confirmation - from GForms'!A1:B;2)) returns 

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that my understanding might not be correct. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike no need to apologize, my english is poor too. I'll be waiting for your message

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to correctly understand your expected result. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to post an answer. When I have a question, I will ask it here.

Comment: `I am asking for advice in which direction to look for information.` I _do_ understand; I suggest constructing a working (manual) proto-type so that you have a clear understanding of what happens, how and when. E.g. have you worked out how to build the pre-filled form?. `a line with the client number and a green dotappears on the “Confirmation - GForms” sheet.` OK, so the Form is linked to the Sheet , you create an `onFormSubmit` script that copies the relevant data to "Confirmation - from GForms" sheet. Why not use the same script to insert the green dot into the "Main Table"? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I found a compromise solution.

I created the following script

```
    function RepairDots() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Main table')
    .createTextFinder("")
    .matchEntireCell(false)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .findAll()
    .forEach(function (range) {
      range.setValue("");
    });
}
```

I also created a image button that launches this script. I just press the button periodically and the green dots themselves turn from a formula to a value. Better than nothing